# How to avoid using highway with distance matrix?

Tags: google-maps, matrix, google-distancematrix-api

I'm calculating route distance and transport time between user specified by LatLng (by dragging marker) with distance matrix api.
But sometimes I got a wrong distance which looks like using toll(or highway) accidentally.

First I have tried:

Rounding origin(and destination) location by reverse geocoding LatLng  with ROOF_TOP option to avoid user specified origin on highway.

I works like a charm to avoid highway origin (or destination).

But then I encounting a problem that distance matrix calculate too long route which looks like using highway.

I have checked estimate route with google-map then google returns route that using highway.

But when I checked Uber-app with same origin and destination (I assumed they using google map's api!!) they returned normal price. So I think there is a solution...but I can't find...

I found moving origin a little can solve this problem (it seems like google assumed one-way traffic accidentally), but how can I programatically solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid highways  [`avoid`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters) parameter in your request. This parameter supports `tolls, highways, ferries and indoors`.

Directions may be calculated that adhere to certain restrictions. Restrictions are indicated by use of `avoid` parameter and an argument to that parameter indicating the restriction to avoid. 
It's possible to request a route avoids any combination of tolls, highways and ferries by passing both restrictions to the avoid parameter.

For example:

```
avoid=tolls|highways|ferries

avoid=tolls

avoid=highways

avoid=ferries
```

Comment: According to API documentation, only one restriction can be specified. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro